# Minecraft server 25565 Refusing connection

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, hosting, networking, minecraft-forge

Here are the server properties:

```
#Minecraft server properties
#Mon Jan 11 19:37:17 UTC 2021
generator-settings=biomesoplenty
op-permission-level=4
allow-nether=true
level-name=world
enable-query=false
allow-flight=true
prevent-proxy-connections=false
server-port=25565
max-world-size=29999984
level-type=DEFAULT
enable-rcon=false
force-gamemode=false
level-seed=
server-ip=192.168.0.111
network-compression-threshold=256
max-build-height=256
spawn-npcs=true
white-list=false
spawn-animals=true
snooper-enabled=true
hardcore=false
resource-pack-sha1=
online-mode=true
resource-pack=
pvp=true
difficulty=1
enable-command-block=false
player-idle-timeout=0
gamemode=0
max-players=20
max-tick-time=60000
spawn-monsters=true
generate-structures=true
view-distance=6
motd=A Minecraft Server
```

I have made many servers before, and have had them working. But for some reason my forge modded server is not working. When I use "canyouseeme.org" it says connection refused on port 25565.

I have added exceptions in the windows firewall. Disabled the firewall and allowed all inbound and outbound traffic to pass through the domain, private and public networks. But it is still returning connection refused.

I am running it on my laptop, and when I go to my desktop I cannot see the server running. However I can connect using Minecraft's 'direct connect' feature and will be able to login to the server and play. But cannot see it is up, nor can my friends play remotely.

What is happening?

I have port forwarded correctly and tripple-checked, even tried different ports to the same avail.
Uninstalled my vpns (as they were blocking access to the router to port forward).
I have restarted the laptop many times.
What is blocking connections to the server? Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you [port forwarded](https://superuser.com/questions/1705116/port-forwarding-on-zte-router)?

Answer (score 0):

You should only need to allow the port over TCP through your firewall, but you will need to check that your router is also forwarding that port to your computer.